# What is use of class names in base/default/template in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community

I am new to magento want to design a new theme. someone else is going to design pages,I am thinking to give him template files, so is it necessary to tell him to keep the class names same as they are in base/default package and he don't know magento theming,first of all is this the way magento theme is developed

If I replace all the classes with new one's will it break magento's functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *lot* of Magento's JavaScript functionality is heavily dependent on these, so it's best that you keep them intact and simply extend them (should you need to, of course) with your own classes.

**Resources:**

- [Front-End Developer Guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/bk-frontend-dev-guide.html)
- [Tips for a Beginner Magento Front-End Developer](http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/beginner-front-end-developer)

Comment: so  those guys who develop their site on bootstrap do they have to write whole js or is there any workaround?

Comment: Absolutely, you can still use JavaScript from Bootstrap, just ensure [non-conflicting jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict) is used to avoid - you guessed it - conflicts. :)